# Is there a Node API for the npm cli tools?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a Node API for the npm cli tools?

For example, if I want to do something like `npm ls --json <package>` in a Node program, do I need to use `exec` or is there a native node API I can use for this?

Ideal:

```js
import { ls } from 'npm';

let dependencies = await ls('lodash');
```

non-ideal:

```js
const util = require('node:util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('node:child_process').exec);

let dependencies = JSON.parse((await exec('npm ls --json lodash')).stdout)
```

Comment: I don't know how extractable it is, but start with how [npm execs commands](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/e5761b9adafe8607ad68baa9599ad4eb228bc6be/lib/npm.js#L99-L110) and the [ls command itself](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/e5761b9adafe8607ad68baa9599ad4eb228bc6be/lib/commands/ls.js)

Comment: After installing npm using `yarn add --dev npm`, `require('npm')` fails: "Error: The programmatic API was removed in npm v8.0.0".

Comment: If I install `npm@latest-7`, I am able to load the npm module without error. It's an older version, of course, but maybe that works for your needs. I couldn't figure out a way to make it return data though; it could only print data to the console.